# Is their an application to extract data from files?

Tags: extract

I want to extract data from large group of files based on a regular expression.

Is their an application, script, batch or terminal command to do this?

Comment: If you want to extract data from regular expressions, I suggest you use regular expression tools, this will help you extract valid data from source code faster You can check this article：https://helpcenter.octoparse.es/hc/es/articles/360040461914-Herramienta-de-Expresi%C3%B3n-Regular-de-Octoparse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[grep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/grep.1.html) should be what you want. It is very powerful. You can search multiple files for a pattern and you can even select the matcher.

There are many many options so you should really look up its man page I've linked you to.

Comment: awk and sed are also very powerful tools for parsing text files.

Comment: @codeMonk very true. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: yes grep is very powerful!! But is there a way to output the found regexp? grep usually outputs the whole line + filename